# Unity, объединение анимации пиксельного персонажа

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, анимация

Есть пиксльный персонаж, есть его анимация, я хочу сделать полное взаимодействие с ним т.е. например ноги у него будут отдельно и на них отдельно можно будет одеть штаны итд и тоже самое с топом, руками итд, но как мне это все объединить в одного персонажа ? Я к примеру разделю персонажа что анимация рук будет отдельно, анимация ног отдельно, анимация топа отдельно, но как это объединить в unity чтоб все было на своих координатах ?

Comment: непонятно, что значит "пиксельный персонаж"? и что значит "все было на своих координатах"?

Comment: Делаешь родительский объект "Персонаж", И дочерние ему: "ноги", "топ"... И в трансформ подгоняешь их позиции(X,Y)

Comment: @ValeraKvip Окей, но допустим мне надо будет сделать анимацию приседания, то тогда как ?

Comment: А в чем проблема приседания, ты же разделил спрайты на части, в чем проблема и в приседании разделить? Или если вопрос в том что ноги подсядут и между ногами и телом будет пустота?  Тогда можно приопустить трансофрм тела(и всего что еще нужно) по Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объединяешь внутри одного объекта, подогнав позиции и всё. 
Придётся нарезать анимации оставив прозрачность там где должна была быть другая часть тела.